# How to calculate weighted average with value and weight in a single column PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to build a measure that calculates the weighted average of some KPIs, but all the data are in a single column.

This is the kind of data I have:

```
Line  Indicator     Value
A     Efficiency    90
B     Efficiency    80
A     Weight        5
B     Weight        10
```

And this measure should return me 83.33, from (90 * 5 + 80 * 10)/(5 + 10).

How can I use DAX to get this result? Or should I use some other method?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pivot the `Indicator` column? It's a bit odd to have you data stored this way.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexisOlson. I pivoted it and now I can get the weighted average easily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pivoted the Indicator column as told by @AlexisOlson, and then calculated the weighted averages using simple SUMX syntax. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you.
First, create a Calculated Column using this DAX Formula:**

```
Column =
 VAR line = 'Table'[Line]
 VAR SubTable = FILTER( 'Table'; 'Table'[Line] = line )
 VAR eff = CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[Value]); 'Table'[Indicator] = "Efficiency"; SubTable )
 VAR w = CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[Value]); 'Table'[Indicator] = "Weight"; SubTable )                                                                           
Return IF( 'Table'[Indicator] = "Efficiency"; eff * w )
```

**Then you have to create a measure like this:**

```
Result =
 VAR SumColumn = SUM( 'Table'[Column] )
 VAR TotalWeight = CALCULATE( SUM( 'Table'[Value] ); 'Table'[Indicator] = "Weight" )                                                                           
Return DIVIDE( SumColumn; TotalWeight; BLANK() )
```

**Hope that helps.**